# marker_icon may be buggy in google_map_update call

Tags: r, shiny, google-maps-markers, googleway

**Problem**

I have a data.frame that contains a column, named "icon", with a link in character format exactly like so "https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDNdX.png".

I am feeding the column name into the google_map_update call in my shiny app:

> ```
> output$map <- renderGoogle_map({
>       google_map(
>         location = c(43.761539, -79.411079),
>         key = api_key,
>         scale_control = F,
>         street_view_control = F
>       ) 
>     })
>
>   observeEvent(
>     input$updateData,  # a button that updates the data 
>     {              
>
>       googleway::google_map_update(map_id = "map") %>%
>         clear_markers() %>%
>         googleway::add_markers(
>           lat = "lat.x",
>           lon = "long.x",
>           marker_icon = "icon", 
>           data = data %>% filter(gender %in% input$gender)
>      }
>   )
> )
> ```

However, when I plot the points, nothing shows. Looking at the Chrome console, I see error 404, url not found error. I can still see the clustered points (the yellow, red and blue signals with a number), but not the individual markers.

**I tried the following**

1. Not including the s in https://
2. Referring to a local file instead, calling it in 2 ways: absolute and relative
3. Using an entirely different link that other sites use (http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png)
4. Looking at SO, but most google map marker question are in Javascript
5. When using it non-shiny, the custom markers work:

> ```
> google_map(
>   location = c(43.761539, -79.411079),
> ) %>%
> googleway::add_markers(
>   data = data,
>   marker_icon = "icon",
>   lat = "lat.x",
>   lon = "long.x",
>   cluster = T
> )
> ```

Comment: What do you see if you don't cluster the markers (`cluster = F`) ?

Comment: And which version of `googleway` are you using? I made a fix to the clustering code in v2.6

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your error. Here's a working example where the markers are being updated, but keeping the `icon` value

```
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

ui <- fluidPage(
  google_mapOutput(outputId = "map", height = "800px"),
  actionButton(inputId = "btn", label = "some people")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  tram_stops$icon <- "http://i.imgur.com/UxVFMcQ.png"
  # set_key("YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY)

  output$map <- renderGoogle_map({
    google_map(data = tram_stops) %>%
      add_markers(lat = "stop_lat", lon = "stop_lon", marker_icon = "icon")
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn, {

    myRow <- sample(1:nrow(tram_stops), 10)

    google_map_update(map_id = "map") %>%
      clear_markers() %>%
      add_markers(data = tram_stops[myRow, ], marker_icon = "icon")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This opens with a map of custom markers

[image]

Then pressing the `some people` button samples ten rows of data, then uses `google_map_update` to update the existing map

[image]

[image]

---

```
devtools::session_info()
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.447)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
 tz       Australia/Melbourne         
 date     2018-05-03                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       source                          
 base        * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
 ...<snip>...                
 googleway   * 2.6     2018-04-29 local                           
 shiny       * 1.0.5   2017-08-23 cran (@1.0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you Symbolix team. Your code works so it must be something else on my end, I'll experiment further and will report back with results. I updated the first chunk of code with more of my current code to show I'm updating an existing map

Comment: I solved the issue, it was unrelated to your package. In an attempt to speed up the map_update, I used select() to select only a few columns (lat,long,info_window) of my data, forgetting to add "icon" to it. I'll delete this question tomorrow - my apologies for taking your time

Comment: @RobertTan It might be useful to other people if you want to leave it up. Up to you though.